# Angularjs state provider

Tags: angularjs

My Boss disabled angularjs url changing using location : false in state routing due to security issue. Is any disadvantages of this ?

Ex:

$state.go("home.foo", {}, { location: false } );

If any solution to secure url without setting location to false plz mention.

Comment: why don't you ask same question to your boss then. :D . Though, I think that will change your router `state` without change in location url.

Comment: He is saying that anyone can be able to modified the url and get the secure data.

Comment: passing secure data from URL isn't good practice..

Comment: Yeah state routing is working well. But i am asking is any disadvantage of this like we are not able to detect last access location when Session is expired.

Comment: Dear plz understand we are not able to send POST req everytime. Ex. When we editing some record than we send it PK id to db to get data. Now point is that how to ensure that PK id is secure and valid and not modified ?

Comment: why don't then have [hashids](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/56385) in the URL instead of ids?

Comment: Ok Thanks @PankajParkar... One more thing i want to know that is any impact on unit testing in angularjs if we disable url update ??